# Why does Scala ignore exclamation points in command line arguments?

Tags: scala, command-line-arguments

If I write a Scala script (or App) that just prints out the command line arguments, I notice that it ignores all the '!' characters.  For example, if my script looks like:

```
println(args(0))
```

And I run it with:

```
scala MyScript "Hello!"
```

I get the output:

```
Hello
```

And if I run it with:

```
scala MyScript "Hello! World!"
```

I also get:

```
Hello
```

What's going on?  What is the purpose of the ! character in arguments that causes this behaviour?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `!` character is being interpreted specially by your shell and this has nothing to do with Scala.

Comment: Which shell are you using? What is the result of using single quotes? `scala MyScript 'Hello! World!'`?

Comment: I'm running it from the Windows command line.  It's not the shell.  I've done the exact same script in Java, and Java reads the ! characters just fine.  If I enclose it in single quotes, like `'Hello World!'` I get `'Hello` and `World'`.

Comment: Interestingly, if I write `scala MyScript "Hello! World! Hi!"` the output is `Hello Hi`, which suggests that scala interprets the `!` character as some kind of delimiter indicating a section of the parameters to ignore.  That suggests that there should be some kind of escape character, but I haven't been able to figure out what, or find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!` is history substitution.

Try `scala MyScript hello!` with `!` at EOL to see it work as if quoted.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes

On windows, the `"scala.bat"` command script has delayed expansion enabled.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#SETLOCAL

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Command-line_arguments

To disable interpretation of `!myvar!`:

```
C:\Users\you> scala greeting.script "hello^!"
hello!

C:\Users\you> set world= Bob

C:\Users\you> scala greeting.script "hello!world!"
hello Bob
```

Comment: I'm working in Windows command line, and when I run an equivalent Java program it picks up the ! character.  It appears to be specific to Scala.

Comment: Delayed expansion doesn't explain why the same parameters work for Java programs, but it's the best answer I've seen so far.  Have an upvote.

Comment: Have a jira issue. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9204  I also clarified the answer here.

Comment: That's great.  I'll keep an eye on the issue status, but thanks for the workaround, too.