# Exclamation (!) as arg in scala

Tags: scala, arguments, escaping, character

I am very new to scala.

Wrote a very basic scala script as below.

```
args.foreach(a=>println(a))
```

Executed the above in command prompt using the following

```
scala test1.scala Happy Scala Programming !!!
```

The output that I expected is

```
Happy
Scala
Programming
!!!
```

But I got the following instead

```
Happy
Scala
Programming
```

As we observe the "!!!" (exclamation characters are missing).

Need to understand why exclamation characters are not printed and what is way to get those characters printed.

I am executing the script on Windows 7 command prompt

Comment: It could have something to do with the shell you are using consuming those characters and doing something with them before executing the command and passing the arguments to your program. You might want to mention what your run environment is, and most specifically the command shell you are using.

Comment: What happens if you wrap the `!!!` in double-quotes?

Comment: c:\scala\samples>scala test1.scala Happy Scala Programming "!!!"
Happy
Scala
Programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use **^** before each exclamation signs and also need to put the whole argument in double quote. So this will work:

```
scala test1.scala "Happy Scala Programming ^!^!^!"
```

This is because **!** is a special character for the windows shell. So this issue has nothing to do with the scala itself as scala program is receiving only **Happy Scala Programming** as program arguments, the exclamations were getting consumed by the windows shell prompt.

Please take a look at these stack overflow answers for more in depth explanations.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28892829/4046067
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322106/4046067

Comment: Since my requirement was to print each word in a new line hence I used the following (added double quotes only around the special characters). Many thanks for the help. scala test1.scala Happy Scala Programming "^!^!^!"